# Test page - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url, testing, custom-wordpress-pages

Can I make a page in wordpress that I can use to test things on and wont be viewable on the actual WordPress site? I need a page that I can just mess around with things because I'm fairly new to WordPress. So you could only get to the page with the url.

Comment: Yes if I remember correctly you can make that page `private` in settings and it will not be shown to public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make page private, then you can save it and preview it from inside wordpress.